# Is it possible to "hide" this generic type parameter in this situation?

Tags: java, generics

The project is this:

https://github.com/ChrisBrenton/grappa-parsetree

The goal is to provide an API to the end user which makes the package easy enough to use. And currently, [this](https://github.com/ChrisBrenton/grappa-parsetree/tree/topic/api/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbrenton/grappa/parsetree/api) is the proposal.

First, an example usage:

```
final ParseTree<Void, SentenceNode> parseTree = ParseTree
    .usingParser(SentenceParser.class)
    .withRule(SentenceParser::sentence)
    .withRoot(SentenceNode.class);
```

The code to achieve this, from the link above, replicated here (imports/package declarations omitted):

### ParseTree.java

```
public final class ParseTree<T, N extends ParseNode>
{
    private final Rule rule;
    private final ParseNodeConstructorProvider provider;
    private final Class<N> nodeClass;

    public static <T, P extends BaseParser<T>> ParseTreeBootstrap<T, P>
        usingParser(final Class<P> parserClass)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(parserClass);
        return new ParseTreeBootstrap<>(parserClass);
    }

    ParseTree(final Rule rule, final ParseNodeConstructorProvider provider,
        final Class<N> nodeClass)
    {
        this.rule = rule;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.nodeClass = nodeClass;
    }

    public N parse(final CharSequence input)
    {
        final ParseRunner<T> runner = new ParseRunner<>(rule);

        final ParseTreeBuilder<T> builder = new ParseTreeBuilder<>(provider);

        runner.registerListener(builder);

        if (!runner.run(input).isSuccess())
            throw new GrappaException("parsing failed! Cannot retrieve the tree");

        return nodeClass.cast(builder.getTree());
    }
}
```

### ParseTreeBootstrap.java

```
public final class ParseTreeBootstrap<T, P extends BaseParser<T>>
{
    private final P parser;
    private final ParseNodeConstructorProvider provider;

    ParseTreeBootstrap(final Class<P> parserClass)
    {
        parser = Grappa.createParser(parserClass);
        provider = new ParseNodeConstructorProvider(parserClass);
    }

    public ParseTreeRule<T, P> withRule(final Function<? super P, Rule> fn)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(fn);
        return new ParseTreeRule<>(parser, provider, fn);
    }
}
```

### ParseTreeRule.java

```
public final class ParseTreeRule<T, P extends BaseParser<T>>
{
    private final Rule rule;
    private final ParseNodeConstructorProvider provider;

    ParseTreeRule(final P parser, final ParseNodeConstructorProvider provider,
        final Function<? super P, Rule> fn)
    {
        rule = fn.apply(parser);
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public <N extends ParseNode> ParseTree<T, N> withRoot(final Class<N> nodeClass)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(nodeClass);
        return new ParseTree<>(rule, provider, nodeClass);
    }
}
```

The problem I have here is with the initial declaration of ParseTree:

```
final ParseTree<Void, SentenceNode> parseTree = ...
```

The first type parameter is there because it is the type parameter of the parser itself:

```
public class SentenceParser
    extends BaseParser<Void>
```

but when producing a parse tree, this type is irrelevant to the end user.

I have tried to ignore it, but then the problem comes from this method in `ParseTree`:

```
    public N parse(final CharSequence input)
    {
        final ParseRunner<T> runner = new ParseRunner<>(rule);

        final ParseTreeBuilder<T> builder = new ParseTreeBuilder<>(provider);

        runner.registerListener(builder);

        if (!runner.run(input).isSuccess())
            throw new GrappaException("parsing failed! Cannot retrieve the tree");

        return nodeClass.cast(builder.getTree());
    }
```

I cannot substitute `N` for `?` here because if I do so, then I cannot `.registerListener()` (captures are different).

One solution would probably be to use raw types; but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

How would you avoid having to declare the first type parameter here?

Comment: Under what circumstances would you have a `ParseTree<T, N>` where `T` isn't `Void`?

Comment: Is composition a viable option? Something like the following should work: `class MyParseTree<N extends ParseNode> { private final ParseTree<Void, N> parseTree = ParseTree.usingParser(SentenceParser.class).withRule(SentenceParser::sentence).withRoot(SentenceNode.class); ...}`

Comment: @user2357112 in any situation in fact. The type parameter here is the type of values pushed on the parser's stack. They may be used internally by the parser itself for purposes which are irrelevant to the parse tree generated

Comment: @RomanVottner it could be a viable option indeed; I haven't thought about that. The API is still being designed at this stage.

Comment: I don't see a ParseRunner class in this codebase.

Comment: @user2357112 it is not part of this package, it is part of grappa -- [link](https://github.com/fge/grappa/blob/039456eca60e17f809c7152fd4790e291ab73511/src/main/java/com/github/fge/grappa/run/ParseRunner.java#L69-L69)